# How to change output names when batch converting with ffmpeg to the same directory?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, batch, conversion

I have a bunch of mkv files that I'm trying to convert their audio while copying the video with this command:

```
for %i in (*.mkv) do ffmpeg -i "%i" -c:a aac -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -c:v copy "?"
```

I want ffmpeg to rename the output files into either "output1.mkv" "output2.mkv" etc or to copy the source names and add converted to them, for example, "X.mkv" into "X converted.mkv" etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've used *%i* as your variable with **for**,

%~ni = File name
%~xi = File extension
(See `for /?` for more.)

So use "%~ni converted%~xi".

Comment: Thank you, this copies the name and adds converted but what if I want the output to be output1.mkv output2.mkv  our 1.mkv 2.mkv etc?.